# windows store submission issue for privacy policy

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, uwp, win-universal-app

After Submission to Windows Store I am Getting the Following Issues :-

**App Policies: 10.1 Inaccurate Functionality**
Your app and its associated metadata must accurately and clearly reflect the source, functionality, and features of your app.
All aspects of your app should accurately describe the functions, features and any important limitations of your app, including required or supported input devices. Your app may not use a name or icon similar to that of other apps, and may not claim to be from a company, government body, or other entity if you do not have permission to make that representation.
Your app must be fully functional and must provide appropriate functionality for each targeted device family.
Keywords may not exceed seven unique terms and should be relevant to your app.
Your app must have distinct and informative metadata and must provide a valuable and quality user experience.

Tested OSes: Windows 10 Mobile
Tested Devices: Acer Iconia W700, Lumia 650

Notes To Developer
**The app contains placeholder content that impairs access to core functions of the app.**

App Policies: 10.5.1 Privacy Policy
The following requirements apply to apps that access personal information. Personal information includes all information or data that identifies or could be used to identify a person, or that is associated with such information or data. Examples of personal information include: name and address, phone number, biometric identifiers, location, contacts, photos, audio & video recordings, documents, SMS, email, or other text communication, screen shots, and in some cases, combined browsing history.
If your app accesses, collects or transmits personal information, or if otherwise required by law, you must maintain a privacy policy. You must provide users with access to your privacy policy by entering the privacy policy URL in Dev Center when you submit your app. In addition, you may also include or link to your privacy policy in the app. The privacy policy can be hosted within or directly linked from the app. Your privacy policy must inform users of the personal information accessed, collected or transmitted by your app, how that information is used, stored and secured, and indicate the types of parties to whom it is disclosed. It must describe the controls that users have over the use and sharing of their information and how they may access their information, and it must comply with applicable laws and regulations. Your privacy policy must be kept up-to-date as you add new features and functionality to your app.

Additionally, apps that receive device location must provide settings that allow the user to enable and disable the app's access to and use of location from the Location Service API. For Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 apps, these settings must be provided in-app. For Windows Mobile 10 apps, these settings are provided automatically by Windows within the Settings App (on the Settings->Privacy->Location page).
You may publish the personal information of customers of your app to an outside service or third party through your app or its metadata only after obtaining opt-in consent from those customers. Opt-in consent means the customer gives their express permission in the app user interface for the requested activity, after you have:
described to the customer how the information will be accessed, used or shared, indicating the types of parties to whom it is disclosed, and
provided the customer a mechanism in the app user interface through which they can later rescind this permission and opt-out.
If you publish a person’s personal information to an outside service or third party through your app or its metadata, but the person whose information is being shared is not a customer of your app, you must obtain express written consent to publish that personal information, and you must permit the person whose information is shared to withdraw that consent at any time. If your app provides a customer with access to another person’s personal information, this requirement would also apply.
If your app collects, stores or transmits personal information, it must do so securely, by using modern cryptography methods.
Your app must not collect, store or transmit highly sensitive personal information, such as health or financial data, unless that information is related to the primary purpose of the app.
Your app must not collect, store or transmit personal information unrelated to its primary purpose, without first obtaining express user consent.

Tested OSes: Windows 10 Mobile
Tested Devices: Acer Iconia W700, Lumia 650

Notes To Developer
**The privacy policy provided for this app fails to inform users of the personal information transmitted by your app and how that information is used, stored, secured, and disclosed. See policy 10.5.1 for details about the requirements for a privacy policy.**

I have already stated the privacy policy indicating the use of names ,private data etc. What needs to be done for this type of issue? Any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> What needs to be done for this type of issue?

Without seeing your app, it's really hard to make detailed advice at forum. Regarding this type of question, it will be more appropriate to [**create a support ticket**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support) through your developer account so that support can give you specific suggestion after reviewing your submission.

You may rewrite your privacy policy following [**How To Add a Privacy Policy to Windows Phone Apps**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-US/aa0c65c9-73a5-432e-ad59-208b17bb04a1/how-to-add-a-privacy-policy-to-windows-phone-apps?forum=wphowto#aa0c65c9-73a5-432e-ad59-208b17bb04a1), which is old but you can still find some useful info within it.

Comment: I am using user's current location to get places near him/her with the help of google maps api, do i need to get special certifation from google and microsoft as well reagrding this personal informatin and specify how it is handled ? thanks

Comment: You don't need to get that special certification but you need to implement a method to obtain the user's "opt-in" consent. You may provide your privacy policy within your app and describe how the information will be accesses, used or shared.